# Using vlock without changing VT from X

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, screen-lock

X screen lockers are fine, but I sometimes have stuff open on other TTYs that I want to lock as well. For this reason I would like to use `vlock -a` to lock all TTYs at the same time. However, I am typically in an X session when I want to run this command.

`vlock` cannot be run from within X because it complains that the current terminal is not a virtual console. I tried to make some solution with `chvt` but I don't know how to run the command in that console afterwards.

How can I lock all TTYs without exiting X (preferably using `vlock`, but I'm open to other suggestions)?

Answer (score 4):

See this command line option:

```
   -n,--new
          Switch to a new virtual console before locking all console sessions.
```

What I always do is `sudo vlock -ans`, works inside / outside  Xorg.

It will jump back to the original VT when you unlocked it.

**EDIT**

Too bad, Arch Linux replaced the original vlock package with the one provided by `kbd` package. That one can lock only the current console, which is useless to you. (none of `-a -n -s` is supported, sigh)

The workaround can be tricky, you must manually install the original vlock, and mask `kbd` from upgrading in `pacman.conf`

[See this link for further information](https://mailman.archlinux.org/pipermail/aur-general/2013-July/024662.html)

Comment: I do not have this option in my version of vlock (Arch Linux). Any idea how to get it?

Comment: @user66104 Too bad, check my update please

Answer (score 3):

If your heart is not set on using `vlock`, you should take a look at [`physlock`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/physlock/). Physlock does exactly what it seems that you are looking for: it switches to a new VT, locks it and disables console switching. Upon unlocking, you are returned to whatever console you were on when you invoked it (and it can be invoked from X or from a TTY).

It has a great set of options and remains incredibly light-weight; I actually use it for my default screenlocker in combination with `xautolock`.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** your idea with `chvt` was almost correct this is the command line

```
sudo openvt -s -- sudo -u "$(whoami)" "$SHELL" -c \
  'vlock -a; chvt '"$(sed 's/^tty//' < /sys/devices/virtual/tty/tty0/active)"
```

it uses `openvt -s/--switch` to run the vlock on a newly opened tty and switches back after unlock previous tty as retrieved via `/sys/devices/virtual/tty/tty0/active` (i.e. your tty with X running).

**long story**

while your question's title

> us[e] vlock without changing VT from X

appears to suggest that you desire an answer that prevents a change of the `vt`/`tty` it appears you yet would like the `vlock -a` functionality and attempted `chvt`. This answer provides a solution that follows your original idea of `chvt`.

```
# get the currently active tty 
# (via https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/554600/24394)
ACTIVE_TTY="$(cat /sys/devices/virtual/tty/tty0/active)"
# get current user 
ACTIVE_USER="$(whoami)"

# get the current shell or fallback
test -x "$SHELL" && ACTIVE_SHELL="$SHELL" || ACTIVE_SHELL="/bin/bash"

# 1. sudo open and switch to new tty 
# 2. sudo run as ACTIVE_USER the ACTIVE_SHELL with
# 3. vlock -a to lock down
# 4. and upon unlock print unlocked and
# 5. switch back to previous shell
sudo openvt --switch --\
  sudo -u "$ACTIVE_USER" "$ACTIVE_SHELL" -c \
    'vlock -a; echo unlocked; chvt '"${ACTIVE_TTY/tty/}"  


sudo openvt --switch -- sudo -u "$(whoami)" "$SHELL" -c 'vlock -a; chvt '"$(sed 's/^tty//' < /sys/devices/virtual/tty/tty0/active)"
```