# Determine which tty is in the "foreground" / "currently displayed"?

Tags: tty, monitors

In linux I can use the key combinations `Alt-Ctrl-F1`,`Alt-Ctrl-F2`... to switch to different `tty1` as I could use `man chvt`.

using the command `tty` I also get displayed the teletype/linux virtual console I am on.

However if I am in `xterm` or in `gnome-terminal` tty will display the relevant pseude-terminal.

Given all that:

- How can I tell which is the currently "active" `tty` (meaning it being displayed on the screen)?

This would be somewhat the solution (however it seems contorted and relies on loginctl logind, there must be a **non-systemd** to find out):

```
for sessionid in $(loginctl list-sessions --no-legend | awk '{ print $1 }'); do loginctl show-session -p State -p TTY  $sessionid; done | grep "State=active" -B1 | head -n 1 | sed 's/.*=//g'
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you asking which of the virtual ttys (`tty1` through `tty12`) is the one being shown to the console user? If so, what would you expect to be reported when a GUI is running on (say) `tty8`? What if the GUI is running remotely as an X Windows session over XDMCP and the user isn't local?

Comment: @roaima thanks for the comment. There will be only local GUIs on ttys. I would like to get the tty for which `loginctl show-session -p State {SESSION_ID}` would yield `State=active`. Hence the `tty` on which either `wayland compositor` or `Xorg server` are running on if they are displayed. No remote GUIs.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski **:) Yes,** that seems to work. `cat /sys/devices/virtual/tty/tty*/active` yields `tty2` which is the tty wayland-compositor is running on currently

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cat /sys/devices/virtual/tty/tty0/active
```

`tty0` refers to the current virtual console (compare [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60649/108618)). By reading `/sys/devices/virtual/tty/tty0/active` you can learn which console this is.

"Current" means what you see, not where `cat` is running. E.g. if you start this loop

```
while sleep 1; do
   cat /sys/devices/virtual/tty/tty0/active
done
```

let in run, manually switch to another console, wait few seconds and switch back, then you will see the other console was reported when you were looking at it.

Comment: A while back I wrote improved manual pages covering this:  http://jdebp.uk./Proposals/linux-kvt-manual-pages.html 
http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/linux-vt.xml

Comment: what about pts / pseudoterminals within a tty? E.g. with tmux, it's possible to have several panes open, each having its own dedicated pts, e.g. `/dev/pts/3` and `/dev/pts/56`.

Comment: @Abdull Uhm… `tty` from the second sentence of the question? In tmux the format variable `pane_tty` should also tell you this, but it's more powerful since you can target any pane; e.g. `tmux display-message -t %0 -p '#{pane_tty}'`.